# Hide egg-info folders from editable/develop mode

Tags: python, installation, pip

Packages that are frequently changing I install with `pip install -e` to make them editable (like `--develop` for setuptools), which creates a `PACKAGE.egg-info` folder in the install directory.  This clutters the folder (sorry, I'm neurotic) and hampers path autocomplete in the folder.

Is there a way hide the egg-info folder, e.g. `.PACKAGE.egg-info`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't, the tooling that creates and reads those files are not so flexible that they'll accept `.NAME.egg-info` as an alternative to `NAME.egg-info`.

Instead, configure your shell or editor to ignore files with the `.egg-info` extension when autocompleting.

E.g., for VI, use the [`wildignore` option](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildignore%27):

```
set wildignore+=*.egg-info
```

or in bash, set [`FIGNORE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-FIGNORE):

```sh
export FIGNORE=".egg-info:$FIGNORE"
```